# How to download an existing folder as zip?

Tags: shiny, download, zip

I wana know how to download a folder an all the files inside it. I have try this:

UI.

```
downloadButton("downloadresults")
```

Server

```
#To create the directory where store the files
dir.create(session$token) 

#Action on download button
output$download <- downloadHandler(
filename <- function(){
  paste("Results","zip", sep = ".")
  },
content <- function(file) {
  path <- session$token
  files <- list.files(path, recursive = T)
  zip(file, files)
  },
contentType = " application/zip"
)
```

This returns an html file. Why is this happening? How do active download the folder as .zip.

**EDIT ONE**

Due to @YBS coment I changed UI:

```
downloadButton("download")
```

This does not download the file and I did not get any error or warning message

**EDIT TWO**

So far I have managed to accomplish download the files using the following code:

UI:

```
downloadButton("download ")
```

Server

```
#To create the directory where store the files
dir.create(session$token)

#Action on download button
output$download <- downloadHandler(
filename = function(){
  paste(" Results", "zip", sep = ".") 
  },
content = function(file) {
  path <- session$token
  zip::zipr(file, path)
  },
contentType = " application/zip"
)
```

I get this:

Results.zip

- session$token folder

  1. filename.hdf5
  2. filename.csv

And I wanna get this:

Results.zip

1. filename.hf5
2. filename.csv

Comment: In ui, you should have `downloadButton("download")`. Notice that button is mispelled as buttom.

Comment: @YBS thanks for your suggestion, I try it out and did not work either. Seems like there is something else still wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the answers given by @YBS I managed to solved it as follow:

```
library(shiny)
library(zip)

ui <- fluidPage(
  #Select a number
  numericInput("firstnumber", "Select a number", 1, min = 1),

  #Select another number
  numericInput("secondnumber", "Select a number", 1, min = 1),

  #Make calculation
  actionButton("calculation","GO"),

  #Alert results are ready
  uiOutput("alert"),

  #Download button
  downloadButton("download")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #To create directory
  dir.create(session$token)

  #To create folder inside directory
  FOLDER <- paste0(session$token,"/Folder")
  dir.create(FOLDER)
  
  #Reactive value to store the path of all the files in the directory
  mylist <- reactiveValues()
  mylist$files <- NULL
  
  #Go button action
  observeEvent(input$calculation,{

    #Calculations
    SUM <- input$firstnumber + input$secondnumber
    SUBSTRACTION <- input$firstnumber - input$secondnumber
    DIVIDE <- input$firstnumber/input$secondnumber
    MULTIPLY <- input$firstnumber *  input$secondnumber

    #Storing results in a data frame
    S_and_S <- data.frame(SUM,SUBSTRACTION)
    D_and_M <- data.frame(DIVIDE,MULTIPLY)

    #Alert results are ready
    output$alert <- renderUI({
      h5("Results are ready", style = "color:green")
    })

    #Saving data frame in directory as Results.csv
    write.csv(S_and_S, file = paste0(session$token,"/Results.csv"))

    #Savin data frame in directory as results.csv
    write.csv(D_and_M, file = paste0(FOLDER,"/results.csv"))

    #Store all the path of the files in the directory in the reactive value
    mylist$files <- list.files(session$token,"*.*")
  })
  
  #Action on download button
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      "Results.zip"
    },
    content = function(file){
      
      files <- c()
      
      for (i in 1:length(mylist$files)) {
        files[i] <- paste0(session$token,"/",mylist$files[i])
      }
      
      zipr(zipfile = file, files = files)
    },
    
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @YBS I just added the e.g of creating and storing a file on the directory. Do you think that the example is enough? , because users can use different saving methods but the important is to specify the correct path (in this case `paste0(session$token, "/filename.fileextension") `.

Comment: @YBS in fact you can download multiple types of files regardless of the extension. That is why I think the most important part of the creating file example is how to specify the file path, and for that I am asking if the example is good enough or should I add others with different saving functions?

Comment: @YBS fully reproducible example added. It is ok?

Comment: Looks great.  However, results.csv has one record with the calculation you do inside the server.  I thought you wanted to "download a folder and all the files inside it".  Perhaps I misunderstood your expectation.

Comment: @YBS I'm getting exactly what I wanted: Results.zip file with all the content of the session$token directory (files and folder and files inside folders...) I may have not explain myself clearly

Comment: That is fine.  I am only getting Results.csv (one line), and inside the Folder another file named results.csv (one line).  No other files are in the zip file for me.  Do you run any other package?

Comment: @YBS I only use shiny and zip package and a I get in both Results.csv and results.csv file two lines: one with columns names and other with the values